# Spring Reactive WebClient thows java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NETWORK_INTERFACES on MockMvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

I am trying to use MockMvc to perform tests on my code that uses Spring Reactive WebClient. But it throws an error when the request is synchronous `.block()`

I have the following in my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>4.9.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockwebserver</artifactId>
        <version>4.9.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

And the following Test to demonstrate the error

```
    private MockWebServer mockWebServer;

    @Test
    public void someTestHere() throws InterruptedException {

        this.webClient = WebClient.create(mockWebServer.url("/").toString());
        this.webClient.get().uri("hello").retrieve().toBodilessEntity().block();
```

The last line throws an error with the following Stack Trace

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NETWORK_INTERFACES
 at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolver.anyInterfaceSupportsIpV6(DnsNameResolver.java:170)
 at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolver.(DnsNameResolver.java:122)
 at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolverBuilder.(DnsNameResolverBuilder.java:52)
 at reactor.netty.transport.NameResolverProvider.newNameResolverGroup(NameResolverProvider.java:501)
 at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpResources.getOrCreateDefaultResolver(TcpResources.java:315)
 at reactor.netty.http.HttpResources.getOrCreateDefaultResolver(HttpResources.java:162)
 at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConfig.defaultAddressResolverGroup(HttpClientConfig.java:392)
 at reactor.netty.transport.ClientTransportConfig.resolverInternal(ClientTransportConfig.java:224)
 at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConfig.resolverInternal(HttpClientConfig.java:446)
 at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$MonoHttpConnect.lambda$subscribe$0(HttpClientConnect.java:269)
 at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate.subscribe(MonoCreate.java:58)
 at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen.subscribe(FluxRetryWhen.java:77)
 at reactor.core.publisher.MonoRetryWhen.subscribeOrReturn(MonoRetryWhen.java:46)
 at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:57)
 at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$MonoHttpConnect.subscribe(HttpClientConnect.java:276)
 at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
 at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
 at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4490)
 at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1741)
 at org.xxx.xxx.xxx.service.xxx.someTestHere(XXXXTest.java:49)
```